# Density not suming to 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, probability-density

I am surprised to see that the probability density doesn't sum to 1. Is there a tweak to make it equal to 1?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
plt.style.use('seaborn-deep')

#input file is a flat file that contains portfolio holdings and characteristics
input_file = r'\\CP\file.xls'

df = pd.read_excel(input_file,header=6)

#number of lines in Fund is 123
df_Fund=df[(df['Port. Weight']>0)]

#number of lines in Bench is 214
df_Bench=df[(df['Bench. Weight']>0)]

#Delta distribution
x = df_Fund['Delta']
y = df_Bench['Delta']

plt.hist([x,y],bins=10, density=True, range=(0,100), label=['Fund','Bench'])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
plt.title='Delta Breakdown'
plt.show()
```

Graph:

[image: screenshot of graph]

Comment: "Is there a tweak to make it equal to 1?" => I assume you know what normalization is if you expect your density to sum up to one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to sum to one, then you divide by the total sum.

For example if you are summing up some components and the sum to a number `X`

```
x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + ... = X
```

so if you then it you divide each component by the total you get

```
(x_0/X) + (x_1/X) + (x_2/X) + ... = (x_0+x_1+x_2...)/X = X/X = 1
```

which is how you normalise any distribution (if the distribution is continuous then the sum becomes an integral)

hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)

> density bool, default: False
>
> If True, draw and return a probability density: each bin will >display the bin's raw count divided by the total number of counts >and the bin width (density = counts / (sum(counts) * >np.diff(bins))), so that the area under the histogram integrates to >1 (np.sum(density * np.diff(bins)) == 1).
>
> If stacked is also True, the sum of the histograms is normalized to 1.

The density is not also weighted by the bin width. As it looks like a binning of approximately 10, I would expect your data to sum to `0.1` instead of `1`.

The way to interpret your graph is "For every x between 50 and 60 the probability is 1.75%"

So in order to "tweak" it to one, you either use a bin size of `1`

```
bins=range(100)
```

or - as mentioned in the other answers - normalize your probabilities